# How can I achieve a View like the Facebook-Posts via Objective-C/Storyboards?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, user-interface, storyboard

I would like to create a View/ViewController where I can add rectangles like this: [image]

When the text expands the rectangle to a specific maximum size, a "Show more" button pops up to expand the rectangle and pushes other UI-Elements down. I prefer to not use a TableView.

How can I achieve something like this? I have spent the whole day looking for tutorials/example codes but I couldn't find anything. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there is any off-the-shelf solution you can search for. You need to roll up your sleeves and develop this yourself. Generally when you want a field that's growing to push something else out of the way you want to use AutoLayout constraints.

Comment: Is there not even a 3rd party solution I could use? I am not that good as a programmer to be honest.

Comment: I have a solution but I don't think you'll understand it, if I post if you will probably not respond and spend a couple of days trying to figure out why it works

Comment: I think it's worth having a look

Comment: Developing finished apps is more than googling for somebody else's work that you can copy and paste. You frequently come across novel problems that you need to do NEW DEVELOPMENT to solve. You can learn the concepts from tutorials and examples, but then you need to apply those concepts yourself. It's like a painter saying "I got a job to do a specific still life. Can I find a paint-by-numbers to create my painting?" No, you can't.